# Resolve variable read from file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to read part of a line from a `.txt` file, which holds a filename. I use that filename to execute several commando's. However, the variable doesn't seem to resolve correctly.

file.txt

> Lookup-File: file.tar.gz

code

```
lookupFileMD5=`grep -A1 ^Lookup-File $metadataFile | grep ^MD5-Digest | cut -d' ' -f2`
    echo "lookupFileMD5=$lookupFileMD5"
    lookupFileMD5downloaded=`md5sum $path/$lookupFileName | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

output

> 2016-09-29 13:57:00 [INFO] - ++ grep -A1 '^Lookup-File' file.txt
>
> 13:57:11           2016-09-29 13:57:02 [INFO] - ++ cut '-d ' -f1
>
> 13:57:11           2016-09-29 13:57:02 [INFO] - ++ md5sum $'/path/file.tar.gzr'
>
> 13:57:11           2016-09-29 13:57:02 [INFO] - md5sum: /path/file.tar.gz
>
> 13:57:11           : No such file or directory

problem

The actual filename is file.tar.gz but in the command (last line) it resolves to `md5sum $'/path/file.tar.gzr'`, with the additional `$'..r'`.

Comment: Either your script or your text file uses DOS line endings; the `r` (presumably `\r`) is the carriage-return half of the line ending being included in the value.

Comment: @chepner Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I see you marked it as duplicate, ignore my previous question